# Http 500 Internal Server Error on POST Request

Tags: http, post, request

I'm trying to send data to server with POST method but I got 500 Internal Server Error. Here's my codes. What do I need to fix this? Thank you.

Rest API POST Method

```
   public void Post([FromBody]OrderLineTerminalViewModel[] OrderLineItems)
    {
        foreach (var OrderLineItem in OrderLineItems)
        {
               …………
        } 
        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

MODEL

```
public class OrderLineTerminalViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal Qtty { get; set; }
    public int ReferanceNumberId { get; set; }
}
```

SAMPLE JSON

```
 [ {'Id':73039,'Unit':'PCS','Qtty':33.0,'ReferanceNumberId':20041},
      {'Id':73040,'Unit':'PC','Qtty':120.0,'ReferanceNumberId':20041}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my API which is working completely fine(**Tested**).
Note:-
Add HttpPost before API method and remove [FromBody].

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("postrequest")]
        public void Post(OrderLineTerminalViewModel[] OrderLineItems)
        {
            //your Code

        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class OrderLineTerminalViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public decimal Qtty { get; set; }
        public int ReferanceNumberId { get; set; }
    }
```

Json:-

```
[ {"Id":73039,"Unit":"PCS","Qtty":33.0,"ReferanceNumberId":20041},
{"Id":73040,"Unit":"PC","Qtty":120.0,"ReferanceNumberId":20041}]
```

Tested

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this but it didn't work.



[HttpPost]       
    public void Post(OrderLineTerminalViewModel[] OrderLineItems)
    {
        foreach (var OrderLineItem in OrderLineItems)
        {     

        }   }


https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5JLp.jpg

Comment: in your json check " is present in last and where is the URL? @MerveTok